# In React Navigation, how can I place Header and Top Tab together without overlapping between them?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm having this problem where a minor overlapping or horizontal line appears. What option or prop do I need to use to remove this?

[image]

This is what I want to achieve: (basically the header on top and top nav tabs underneath it without any overlapping or noticeable lines between them)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether to hide the elevation shadow (Android) or the bottom border (iOS) on the header. This is a short-hand for the following styles:

```
{
  elevation: 0,
  shadowOpacity: 0,
  borderBottomWidth: 0,
}
```

If the above styles are specified in headerStyle along with headerShadowVisible: false, then headerShadowVisible: false will take precedence

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Example"
  component={Example}
  options={({ route }) => ({
    title: route.params.title,
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: route.params.color,
    },
    headerShadowVisible: false, // applied here
    headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  })}
/>
```